# CSS flying and enlarge logo on curved path

Tags: css, animation, bezier, cubic

I have to make an animation with css. A logo flying and enlarging into the front based on a curved path or parabola. I made a small sketch.
The logo is staring small top right, flying and getting larger and is ending left center.
[Sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNEec.jpg)
I found a lot of informations about cubic-bezier also cubic-bezier editors, but unfortnatelly I am not able to realize this.

The html

```
<div class="animation"><img src="logo.jpg"></div>
```

The css

```
.animation {
   transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.725, -0.385, 0.970, 0.465);
   transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.725, -0.385, 0.970, 0.465);
}
```

This was one (of several) trys but the logo isn't animated. Besides, if I understand it, that is only the path without scaling.
Where is my thinking error?

Thanks a lot & regards!

Comment: transition ... is used when you change the properties of the element .... like when you hover

Comment: Do you have a Snippet or Fiddle where we can play with it to experience your problem?

Comment: @DaniP
I'm just searching with google. May it be that these cubic-bezier IS NOT a pathway for an objekt - it is a possibility to define a speed, opacity etc. -> a transition?

Answer (score 0):

First, cubic-bezier is a timing function, not a "path" function. It's not going to accomplish what you are after.

Second, to accomplish what you desire, use the [CSS3 matrix transition property](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2011/01/07/css3-matrix-transform-for-the-mathematically-challenged/) in conjunction with [a custom animation function with a custom step callback](http://cdmckay.org/blog/2010/03/01/the-jquery-animate-step-callback-function/). Either that, or adjust CSS properties like top, left, height, and width directly with said animation function.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you @steve
I just found the possibility to work with keyframes

`code   @keyframes animationFrames{
  0% {transform:  translate(450px,-150px)  scaleX(0.10) scaleY(0.10) ;}
  100% {transform:  translate(0px,0px)  scaleX(1.00) scaleY(1.00) ;} 
} `

Just try to get a kind of curve but it is not a curved path of course.

Comment: @Mr.Paule54 please don't post important information in comments - edit them into your question, and then leave a comment saying "thanks, I've updated the question but it's still not quite working". Other potential question-answerers should be able to find this new information =)